# Phonegap TTS Plugin Android not working

Tags: cordova, text-to-speech, sencha-touch-2.2

I am using the TTS Plugin from https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts But the plugin does not seem to work. It does not even initialize.

Installed the plugin like below (PHONEGAP 3.3 )

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts.git
phonegap build android
```

Added the following in the phonegap config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugins.tts" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.tts"/>
```

Added the following code in my javascript

```
window.plugins.tts.startup(startupWin, fail);
function startupWin(result) {
    console.log("Startup win");
    // When result is equal to STARTED we are ready to play
    if (result == TTS.STARTED) {
        window.plugins.tts.getLanguage(win, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.speak("The text to speech service is ready");
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("en_US", function() {
            addLang("en_US", "English (American)");
        }, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("en_GB", function() {
            addLang("en_GB", "English (UK)");
        }, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("fr", function() {
            addLang("fr", "French");
        }, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("de", function() {
            addLang("de", "German");
        }, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("it", function() {
            addLang("it", "Italian");
        }, fail);
        window.plugins.tts.isLanguageAvailable("es", function() {
            addLang("es", "Spanish");
        }, fail);
    }
}

function addLang(loc, lang) {
    var langs = document.getElementById('langs');
    var langOption = document.createElement("OPTION") 
    langOption.innerText = lang; 
    langOption.value = loc;
    langs.options.add(langOption); 
}

function changeLang() {
    var yourSelect = document.getElementById('langs');
    window.plugins.tts.setLanguage(yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value, win, fail);
}

function win(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

function fail(result) {
    console.log("Error = " + result);
}

function speak() {
    console.log("Speaking");
    window.plugins.tts.speak("How are you");
}
```

But none of the console log messages are displayed. I am testing this on genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some struggle i have the TTS working. But there is still one issue i had to manually fix. Following are the steps to get the TTS Working

Install the plugin like below.

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts.git
phonegap build android
```

Once installed and built. Add this plugin to the phonegap config.xml file. ( If you are building the app using sencha touch, the config.xml will be in the root folder. )

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugins.tts" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.tts"/>
```

This will add the plugin to the final build. Now to start the TTS Service and speak some text, use the following snippet.

```
navigator.tts.startup(startupWin, fail);
function startupWin(result) {
    console.log("Startup win");
    // When result is equal to STARTED we are ready to play
    console.log("Result "+result);
    //TTS.STARTED==2 use this once so is answered
    if (result == 2) {
        navigator.tts.getLanguage(win, fail);
        navigator.tts.speak("The text to speech service is ready");                                     
    }
}                               

function win(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

function fail(result) {
    console.log("Error = " + result);
}
```

The issue i had was the TTS.STARTED in the startupWin is not defined in the plugin. I just used the constant's value and the plugin works perfectly.

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 0):

result == 2 or STARTED works only once. If you again call the function it may not return 2 or STARTED (happened with me). so better dont use that condition in success of startup.

```js
/*********tts.js*************/
var tts = {
    say: function() {
 alert("tts");
    },
    startup: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
 console.log("TTS-Startup");
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "TTS", "startup", []);
    },
    speed: function(speed, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "TTS", "speed", [speed]);
    },
    speak: function(text, successCallback, errorCallback) {
     cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "TTS", "speak", [text]);
    }
  };

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}

if (!window.plugins.tts) {
    window.plugins.tts = tts;
}
/**********calling from your js  after device ready***************/
 function visitToString(){
  window.plugins.tts.startup(function(result){
   window.plugins.tts.speed(50,function(){
    console.log('speed success');
   },function(err){
    console.log('speed err'+JSON.stringify(err));
   });  
       window.plugins.tts.speak(finalstr,function(){
        console.log('speech success');
       },function(err){
        console.log('speech err'+JSON.stringify(err));
       });  
      
 }, fail);
  }
```

```html
<button id="speakvisit" onclick="visitToString();">Audio Details
     </button>
```