# How can I make my webpage say the word?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to build a mobile application that help non-English speaking students learn English

and I am using the HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript/Cordova/jQuery/jQuery mobile

Example -

The user clicks on the word "tiger" and it will say "tiger"

What is the best way to do that?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following jQuery plugin in the past and it works great for this.

http://www.jtalkplugin.com/

Answer (score 1):

Technology you need is called `text to speech` or `TTS`. Try searching TTS for phonegap

Few links regarding TTS for phonegap

[Cordova Speech Plugin (iFlytek Voice Cloud)](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.luhuiguo.cordova.speech)

[org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts](https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts)

[Stakeoverflow Phonegap TTS Plugin Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367203/phonegap-tts-plugin-android-not-working)